# What happens when I declare beans and component-scan both in applicationContext.xml?

Tags: xml, spring, javabeans

I have a project in Java with Spring. I want to ask what happens if I declare beans (in element `<beans>`) and also component-scan into my applicationContext.xml (as shown in code).
I have also annotation `@Component("someName")` in each class.

I have already tried to delete declarations of beans and had only component-scan in my xml - that worked well. When I deleted component-scan and had only declaration of beans in my xml - it caused an error in classes appeared and some classes didnt call other classes.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="vs.project" />
<beans>
     <bean name="create" class="vs.project.command.create"/>
     <bean name="update" class="vs.project.command.update"/>
     <bean name="delete" class="vs.project.command.delete"/>
</beans>
```

I thought it should run well in both cases, but it didnt. So Im asking here how it works and how it works if I declare both - component-scan and beans in applicationContext.xml. Does bean instances create twice? Then why it dont work with no component-scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component-scanning and explicit bean reference are two different things:

1. **Component-scanning**:

`<context:component-scan base-package="vs.project"/>`

This is auto configuration to scan the mentioned package and create and register the beans along with auto-wiring.

2. **Explicit bean reference**:
   Spring expect you to define all the bean references that you bean is having (manual-wiring). So you need to define reference to bean definition explicitly.

   ```
   <bean id = "Driver" class = "vs.project.Driver">
      <property name="license" ref="license"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="license" class="vs.project.License" >
      <property name="number" value="XYZ2434BD"/>
   </bean>
   ```

   or you can define auto-wiring mode as below (this is taken care in case of `component-scan`):

   ```
   <bean id="license" class="vs.project.License" autowire="byName"/>
   ```

Bean instances are only created once and your explicit bean creation take precedence over the component-scanning.

Some reference:

1. [Beans-autowiring-xml](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-beans-auto-wiring-example-using-xml-configuration/)
2. [Beans-classpath-scanning](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-classpath-scanning)
3. [spring-auto-scanning-components](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/)